# Sandwich Sudoku: First 12 digits of pi

Tags: grid-deduction, sudoku

**Sandwich Sudoku**, or "Between 1 and 9 Sudoku", is a variant of Sudoku. A YouTube channel [introduced this variation.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wfR6QIvNn4)

### Rules:

> - Standard Sudoku rules. Place numbers from 1 to 9 in every row, column, and 3×3 box.
> - Additionally, outside the grid, there will be some numbers. The numbers indicate the sum of the numbers physically between 1 and 9 in the respective row or column. (that is, if the row is 953126847, the sum of the numbers between 1 and 9 is 8)

### Puzzle:

[image: Sandwich Sudoku]

Comment: I watched the video... you have to sum the numbers sandwiched between 1 and 9 in the column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is my Sudoku solution:

> [image]
>
>  Solved by hand - method of solving:
>
>  In the first **5** column, the only solution can be 1-2-3-9 going downward.
>
>  In the **31** column, only a 4 goes outside the 1-9 group. The 9 can't be at the top, because the 1 won't go next to another 1. There is already a 9 in the second row. There is already a 1 in the top row, so it must be 1 in second row, 9 in bottom row.
>
>  In the **4** column, the only solution can be 1-4-9 going upward.
>
>  In the **9** column, the only solution can be 1-5-4-9 going downward.
>
>  In the **3** column, the only solution is 9-3-1 going downward.
>
>  In the other **5** column, the solution can't be 1-5-9 downward because there is already a 9 in the bottom row. It can't be 1-2-3-9 or 1-3-2-9 going upward because there is already a 9 in that row. So it must be 1-5-9 going upward.
>
>  In the bottom right block, the 9 can only go in the **8** column. In the **8** column, there is only one place for the 1 to go, for 1-2-6-9 or 1-3-5-9. The only combination that fits is 1-6-2-9.
>
>  I then continued with the normal Sudoku solving methods. Later on the **15** clue was used to find a unique pattern, and the **26** clue wasn't needed - but verified later.

Comment: I keep confusing handwritten 7's without cross-line for 1's, so this one really trips me up.

Comment: @EgorHans many people hand write their 1 with exaggeration so it looks like a 7, but most native English speakers do not. Sometimes a 1 is written like an uppercase Greek *lambda* Λ. In typography there is no need to disambiguate by 'crossing' a 7, as you can see in the grid where an original 7 is placed.

Comment: That's perfectly fair and it wasn't meant to be a critique, just a remark that it looks confusing to me personally.